# Google App Engine routing and pathing

Tags: google-app-engine

I am looking to discover the best possible practice for building up a file tree inside a GAE/python.

It seems rather efficient to keep everything in one file and route everything there via WSGI.

Though for a complex and multifaceted site it makes sense to have distinct files serving different purposes.

I ran into some weird complications when I had many urls listed in the app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /unit3.*
  script: unit3.app

- url: /birthday.*
  script: birthday.app

- url: /signup.*
  script: signup.app

- url: /rot13.*
  script: rot13.app

- url: /welcome.*
  script: signup.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"

- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

and then having to duplicate those paths in separate .py files

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/signup',SignUpHandler),
                               ('/welcome',WelcomeHandler),
                               ('/signup/.*', NotFoundPageHandler)]
                               ,debug=True)
```

Is it weird that I think having to detail the routing of the url twice or more is cumbersome?  Is there a way to have distinct files (html, css, py, js) and then have the app.yaml connect all the dots with the routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to go is use webapp2 framework, routing is very simple there.
You can then just define urls.py and add routes there.
http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/
Routing in webapp.
http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#uri-routing

Here is boilerplate code to get you started.
https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate